# Finding the Stack Trace Log from an EXE that crashes

Tags: c#

I have a c# Console Application that I am running. I have Released it as I would like to do a bit of testing on several computers.

The application sometimes results in an error and a Window popup that forces me to close the application and hence the Console before I can take a look at the exception in question.

Is there any way that I will be able to see the Stack Trace Log similar to running it in Visual Studio? I thought this might be possible through the Windows Event Viewer but I am not entirely sure of this. Or at the very least allow the Console to be visible and not have it automatically close when I've confirmed that there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do all those things you've mentioned. e.g. to see the errors in the console window, you could put a try catch block around your code and call Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadLine() methods.

There is also the stacktrace.tostring() method - e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Console applications automatically close, even if you put Console.WriteLine() in your code. What you need is Console.ReadLine() at the end, perhaps in the finally section of your try catch block.

This way, the console window will stay open.

You can also write events to the event log through your console ap and see them in the event viewer.

This is done through the EventLog.CreateEventSource method using the System.Diagnostics namespace. A link below:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024

Another way is to use system.IO to write lines to a log file (e.g. .txt file), so you can look back at the errors if the process ran late at night for example. In that case, you could use code such as:

```
public static void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("download.log", true);
        textWriter.WriteLine(message);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

and then in your exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Logging.LogMessage(ex.Message);
        }
```